# Storing folders of list of records in Google Drive

Tags: python, performance, http, django, google-drive

I've written a script using the Django ORM to store 'configuration settings' and interacting with the Google Drive API and another API. The script creates a base project folder and subfolders in Google Drive for a list of records, and posts links back to the source database. I'm a beginner in Python, so I'm not sure if I'm doing things the right way, or if it's completely terrible.

I think there are some areas that could be cleaned up -- for example, how I am creating the 'client' and 'service' objects repeatedly inside specific methods. I wasn't sure if it would work to create the objects and pass them between the methods though. I think I could also use the Google 'batch' and 'partial response' methods to optimize HTTP requests.

Also, I need to get this thing on a periodic task or crontab. I was interested in trying celery, so I initially set up the below jobs, and they were creating the clients, but I don't think it's working anymore in Celery.

I removed some of the script and commented areas to make it more understandable.

```
# Celery tasks
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*"))
def sync_folders():
    configs = Configuration.objects.all()
    for config in configs:
        user = config.user
        client = create_client(user, config)
        try:
            create_document_folders(config, client)
        except Exception as inst:
            pass

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="*", minute="5", day_of_week="*"))
def sync_files():
    configs = Configuration.objects.all()
    for config in configs:
        user = config.user
        client = create_client(user, config)
        try:
            get_updated_files(config, client)
        except Exception as inst:
            pass

# Rest of post is the script initiated by celery tasks above. 
def create_client(user, config):
    # Create the QuickBase Client object
    s = config
    if s is not None:
        if s.qb_realm is not None:
            if s.qb_realm != 'www':
                baseurl = 'https://' + s.qb_realm + '.quickbase.com'
            else:
                baseurl = 'https://www.quickbase.com'
        else:
            baseurl = 'https://www.quickbase.com'
        client = quickbase.Client(QUICKBASE_USER, QUICKBASE_PASSWORD, base_url=baseurl)
        return client

def get_jobs_wo_folders(config, client):
    if client is not None:
        query = "{'" + config.root_folder_id + "'.EX.''}"
        clist = [config.root_folder_id, config.root_folder_name_fid, config.root_folder_user, '3']
        records = client.do_query(query, columns=clist, database=config.qb_root_dbid)
        return records

def retrieve_specific_files(service, param):
    # Search and retrieve a list of file resources passing a params object
    result = []
    page_token = None
    while True:
        try:
            if page_token:
                param['pageToken'] = page_token
            files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
            result.extend(files['items'])
            page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
            if not page_token:
                break
        except errors.HttpError, error:
            print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
            break
    return result

def get_csv(list):
    si = cStringIO.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    cw.writerows(list)
    return si.getvalue().strip('\r\n')

# Google helper functions
def refresh_access_token(user, config):
    instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=user, provider='google-oauth2')
    instance.refresh_token()
    # Configuration model has a field 'last_refresh_time' that is auto-now date/time
    config.save()
    return instance.extra_data['access_token']

def get_access_token(config):
    try:
        access_token = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=config.user, provider='google-oauth2').extra_data['access_token']
        return access_token
    except Exception as inst:
        pprint(inst)

def create_drive_service(config):
"""
Creates a drive service using the 'Configuration' object's
related user. Users initial signup is done with django-socialauth;
the access token and refresh token is saved with django-socialauth &
refresh token handling is done with django-socialauth.
"""
    c = config
    user = config.user
    instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=user, provider='google-oauth2')
    refreshed_at = c.token_last_refresh
    now = datetime.now()
    expires_in =  instance.extra_data['expires']
    token_age = (now - refreshed_at).seconds
    if token_age > (expires_in - 120):
        access_token = refresh_access_token(user, config)
    else:
        access_token = instance.extra_data['access_token']

    try:
        credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, 'Python-urllib2/2.7')
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    except Exception as e:
        pprint(e)
    # Are these next lines pointless? What should I do if the tokens consistently fail?
        access_token = refresh_access_token(user)
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

def insert_permission(service, file_id, value, perm_type, role):
    new_permission = {
    'value': value,
    'type': perm_type,
    'role': role,
    }
    try:
        return service.permissions().insert(
            fileId=file_id, body=new_permission, sendNotificationEmails=False).execute()
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occured: %s' % error
    return None

def insert_folder(config, title, parent_idNone, writer=None, mime_type='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'):
    service = create_drive_service(config)
    owner_permission = {
        'role': 'owner',
        'type': 'user',
        'value': 'me',
        }
    body = {
        'title': title,
        'mimeType': mime_type,
        'userPermission': owner_permission,
        'fields': 'items, items/parents',
        }
    if parent_id:
        body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]
    try:
        folder = service.files().insert(
            body=body,
        ).execute()
        insert_permission(service, folder['id'], writer, 'user', 'writer')
        return folder
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occured: %s' % error
        return None

def create_document_folders(config, client):
    """
    Gets records that do not have Google drive folders, 
    and loops through the jobs creating the necessary
    base project folder and subfolders.
    """
    s = config
    records = get_jobs_wo_folders(config, client)
    """
A bunch of logic goes below this to loop through the list of records,
create the new folders, and append the new folder metadata to a the 'rows' list
which is later converted to records_csv
"""
if rows:
        records_csv = get_csv(rows)
    # Create the records in QuickBase
        response = client.import_from_csv(records_csv, clist=folders_clist, database=s.folders_dbid)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Celery tasks
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*"))
def sync_folders():
    configs = Configuration.objects.all()
    for config in configs:
        user = config.user
        client = create_client(user, config)
```

I'd do: `create_client(config.user, config)`

```
        try:
            create_document_folders(config, client)
        except Exception as inst:
            pass
```

Don't do this. You catch an exception and ignore it. You have no clue what went wrong. You should at the very least print out the exception, or put it in a log, or something so you can figure out what what goes wrong.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="*", minute="5", day_of_week="*"))
def sync_files():
    configs = Configuration.objects.all()
    for config in configs:
        user = config.user
        client = create_client(user, config)
        try:
            get_updated_files(config, client)
        except Exception as inst:
            pass
```

Pretty the same function again. Refactor them and pass `get_updated_files` or `create_document_folder` as a parameter to the new function.

```
# Rest of post is the script initiated by celery tasks above. 
def create_client(user, config):
    # Create the QuickBase Client object
    s = config
```

Why? Just use config. The only advantage to s is that it's harder to read.

```
    if s is not None:
```

Do you really want to support config being None?

```
        if s.qb_realm is not None:
            if s.qb_realm != 'www':
                baseurl = 'https://' + s.qb_realm + '.quickbase.com'
```

Generally its  better to use string formatting than concatenation.

```
            else:
                baseurl = 'https://www.quickbase.com'
```

Why is this a special case? it just does the same thing that the above case would do.

```
        else:
            baseurl = 'https://www.quickbase.com'


        client = quickbase.Client(QUICKBASE_USER, QUICKBASE_PASSWORD, base_url=baseurl)
        return client
```

Combine those two lines

```
def get_jobs_wo_folders(config, client):
    if client is not None:
```

Having a function silently fail to do its job given bad input is a bad idea. You should throw an exception. I wouldn't even bother to check if client were None, and just let it fail when it tries to use it.

```
        query = "{'" + config.root_folder_id + "'.EX.''}"
        clist = [config.root_folder_id, config.root_folder_name_fid, config.root_folder_user, '3']
        records = client.do_query(query, columns=clist, database=config.qb_root_dbid)
        return records

def retrieve_specific_files(service, param):
    # Search and retrieve a list of file resources passing a params object
    result = []
    page_token = None
    while True:
        try:
            if page_token:
```

Use `is not None` to check for None, just because a few other random things end up being false and its more explicit this way

```
                param['pageToken'] = page_token
            files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
            result.extend(files['items'])
            page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
            if not page_token:
                break
        except errors.HttpError, error:
            print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
            break
```

Do you really want to try and continue on if there is an error? Shouldn't you just give up this attempt?

```
    return result

def get_csv(list):
```

avoid list as a variable name since its a builtin python type

```
    si = cStringIO.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    cw.writerows(list)
    return si.getvalue().strip('\r\n')

# Google helper functions
def refresh_access_token(user, config):
    instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=user, provider='google-oauth2')
    instance.refresh_token()
    # Configuration model has a field 'last_refresh_time' that is auto-now date/time
    config.save()
    return instance.extra_data['access_token']

def get_access_token(config):
    try:
        access_token = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=config.user, provider='google-oauth2').extra_data['access_token']
```

You just did something very similiar, this suggests that you should extract a common function

```
        return access_token
    except Exception as inst:
        pprint(inst)
```

At least here you print the exception.

```
def create_drive_service(config):
"""
Creates a drive service using the 'Configuration' object's
related user. Users initial signup is done with django-socialauth;
the access token and refresh token is saved with django-socialauth &
refresh token handling is done with django-socialauth.
"""
    c = config
    user = config.user
```

Why do you sometimes use `config.user` and other times pass the user as a parameter?

```
    instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=user, provider='google-oauth2')
```

avoid generic names like instance

```
    refreshed_at = c.token_last_refresh
    now = datetime.now()
    expires_in =  instance.extra_data['expires']
    token_age = (now - refreshed_at).seconds
    if token_age > (expires_in - 120):
        access_token = refresh_access_token(user, config)
```

But you've already got the instand, so this does extra work

```
    else:
        access_token = instance.extra_data['access_token']

    try:
        credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, 'Python-urllib2/2.7')
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    except Exception as e:
        pprint(e)
    # Are these next lines pointless? What should I do if the tokens consistently fail?
        access_token = refresh_access_token(user)
```

You shouldn't need to do this as you've just refreshed the token up there.

```
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

def insert_permission(service, file_id, value, perm_type, role):
    new_permission = {
    'value': value,
    'type': perm_type,
    'role': role,
    }
    try:
        return service.permissions().insert(
            fileId=file_id, body=new_permission, sendNotificationEmails=False).execute()
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occured: %s' % error
    return None


def insert_folder(config, title, parent_idNone, writer=None, mime_type='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'):
    service = create_drive_service(config)
    owner_permission = {
        'role': 'owner',
        'type': 'user',
        'value': 'me',
        }
    body = {
        'title': title,
        'mimeType': mime_type,
        'userPermission': owner_permission,
        'fields': 'items, items/parents',
        }
    if parent_id:
        body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]
    try:
        folder = service.files().insert(
            body=body,
        ).execute()
        insert_permission(service, folder['id'], writer, 'user', 'writer')
        return folder
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occured: %s' % error
        return None

def create_document_folders(config, client):
    """
    Gets records that do not have Google drive folders, 
    and loops through the jobs creating the necessary
    base project folder and subfolders.
    """
    s = config
    records = get_jobs_wo_folders(config, client)
    """
A bunch of logic goes below this to loop through the list of records,
create the new folders, and append the new folder metadata to a the 'rows' list
which is later converted to records_csv
"""
if rows:
        records_csv = get_csv(rows)
    # Create the records in QuickBase
        response = client.import_from_csv(records_csv, clist=folders_clist, database=s.folders_dbid)
```

Comment: @Wintson Ewert - You are the man. I had to move on to other work earlier, but that really helped me think about the script differently. I was passing user sometimes because I wasn't sure if config.user was working when I was debugging parts of the script. I only had one config in my database, and it had a User, so I guess I should assume config.user will always work.

It looks like at the very least, I should do some reading on how to throw exceptions properly, and strip some of the redundancy from the script. Thanks!